# What size and type of wire do I need for a long run?

Tags: electrical, extension-cord

I'm a DJ and need to power five 20A amplifiers. Since the wall receptacles in most clubs and outdoor events to not have sufficient power to make them sound good. I need a 50 foot length and a 100 foot length for outside events.

What  is a good, safe and cost-effective wire to use? And what type of box should I use at the other end by my sound gear? Thanks.

Comment: How are you planning on connecting to power? 100 amps won't be a problem with large heavy duty cord but if at an outside event I would consider type W cord. Are your amplifiers actually drawing 20 amps ea or have 20 amp plugs on them. Also temp power outside will need GFCI protection.

Comment: What type of socket are you plugging into?  A NEMA 14-50?  Normal household outlets won't support *one* 20A amplifier, let alone five.

Comment: What type of power source do you have available to you here?